Koin is unable to resolve the Android context when the app is run outside of the emulator or USB debugging
I am developing an android application which works on emulator fine also when I connect my phone using USB cable it runs perfectly but when I disconnect the USB cable and try to run the debug version of app , it crashes and does not work and I get the following error on my phone
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:549)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
 ... 1 more
Caused by: org.koin.android.error.MissingAndroidContextException: Can't resolve Context instance. Please use androidContext() function in your KoinApplication configuration.
 at org.koin.android.ext.koin.ModuleExtKt.androidContext(ModuleExt.kt:33)
 at balazadeh.nima.rgp.di.ModulesKt$myModules$1$2.invoke(Modules.kt:17)


class MyApp :Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        startKoin {
            androidContext(this@MyApp)
            modules(myModules)
        }
    }
}

this is the class that I have added as a name in manifests
    val myModules = module {
        single { createApiService() }
        single { Room.databaseBuilder(androidContext(),AppDatabase::class.java,"app_database.db").build()       }

        single<ProductRepository> { ProductRepositoryImpl(get(), get<AppDatabase>().productDao()) }

        viewModel { (isNetConnected: Boolean) -> MainViewModel(get(), isNetConnected) }
        viewModel { ProductViewModel(get()) }

        viewModel { SignUpViewModel() }
    }

and these are my models
This is very weird when I connect my phone using USB cable it runs perfectly but when I disconnect the USB cable and try to run the debug version of app , it crashes and does not work and I get face the mentioned error however I have given androidContext(this@MyApp) in the startKoin
